# Mocking service inside a service in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, mocking, karma-runner

I have the following services:

**DataService.js**

```
app.service("DataService", [
  function () {
    this.getData = function () { return "original value" }
  }
]);
```

**LocationService.js**

```
app.service("LocationService", ["DataService", 
  function(dataSvc) {
    this.getLocationData = function () {
      return dataSvc.getData();
    }
  }
]);
```

Now for testing LocationService.js, how do mock DataService inside of LocationService?

This is what I currently have for LocationService_tests.js:

```
describe("LocationService", function () {
  var locationSvc;
  beforeEach(module('myModule'));
  beforeEach(inject(function (LocationService) {
    locationSvc = LocationService;
  }));

  describe("getLocationData", function () {
    it("returns the location data", function () {
      var mockLocationDataValue = "mocked value";
      // ???
      // I want to mock dataSvc.getData within getLocationData
      //  so it returns "mocked value" instead of "original value"
      expect(locationSvc.getLocationData()).toBe(mockLocationDataValue);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could mock whole service using `$provide` API's `service` method, and change your `service` to returned `mock data`.

```
describe("LocationService", function () {
  var locationSvc;
  beforeEach(module('myModule'));
  beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
     $provide.service('LocationService', function() {
       this.getData = function() {
          return "mock value";
       }
     });
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function (LocationService) {
    locationSvc = LocationService;
  }));
  ...
});
```

Comment: That worked! I cleaned it up a bit though and placed everything under one `beforeEach` to clean it up a bit.